# Generalization of the independence complex of a graph to simplicial complexes

Tags: reference-request, definition, simplicial-complex

Let $G$ be a graph, then the independence complex of $G$, which we denote $I(G)$, is the set of subsets of the vertex set of $G$ such that no two vertices within a set in $I(G)$ are connected by an edge.

I'm wondering if there is any natural generalization of this from graphs to arbitrary simplicial complexes?